# More elegant Rails routing then a giant list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have an administration controller for my Rails application, but its getting large and unwieldly. Here is a sample:

```
get '/administration/events', :controller => :administration, :action => :event_index
get '/administration/events/new', :controller => :administration, :action => :event_new
post '/administration/events/create', :controller => :administration, :action => :event_create
get '/administration/events/:id/edit', :controller => :administration, :action => :event_edit
post '/administration/events/:id/update', :controller => :administration, :action => :event_update
delete '/administration/events/:id/delete', :controller => :administration, :action => :event_delete
```

It works, but is there a better way of doing it? (my actual routes for the controller are 3 or 4 times this number of entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have build one giant controller with a lot of actions handling a set of resources. The example you show: `events`. This should be in a separate `Administration::EventsController`.

Your url's seem REST-style, now you should match that to your app-structure.

Your directory structure should look like this

```
/app
  /controllers
    /administration
      events_controller.rb
      ..
```

And then your routing will become

```
namespace :administration do
  resources :events
  # ... other resources ...
end
```

Comment: What if I have an "events_controller" already? This is for special administration actions on events (and other resources). Is this ok?

Comment: Sure, that is no problem at all. For example I had a rails project where the EventsController was for front-ent users, `admin/events_controller` for the admin, and `api/events_controller` for the api (all with slightly different behaviour). I prefer that instead of mixing that in one big controller. They do share the same `Event` model.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [namespacing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) instead:

```
namespace :administration do
  resources :events
end
```